# Free web service to determine IP address zip code

Tags: web-services, geolocation

Does anyone know of a free web service to determine the zip code of an IP address?

Comment: I assume that you are aware that not all IP addresses can be associated with a ZIP code in the US? Do you also want to handle international visitors?

Comment: I heard there's a world outside the US, but I don't believe people outside the US even have Internet access. There's no Comcast there, right?

Comment: i'm pretty sure the internet all flows from Californy

Comment: it's limited here in the UK, we get 5 minutes a day (though this is an illegal setup with a ethernet cable trailed across the atlantic into a underground lair), i've wasted my months usage on this comment

Answer (score 9, accepted):

MaxMind GeoLite City

http://www.maxmind.com/app/geolitecity

Comment: If you don't mind paying a bit of money, their GeoIP City product is more accurate and only costs $20 for 50,000 queries.  More info at http://www.maxmind.com/app/city

Answer (score 4):

I realize this question is old, but this may still help other people.  I found a free / open source (so you can even run your own instance and not be subject to their hourly limit of 10,000 requests) IP geolocation database:
http://freegeoip.net/

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any that will return a zipcode, but this one is free and returns city/state

http://www.hostip.info/

Comment: I smell a follow-up question:  "Free web service to determine zip code from city/state"

Comment: Beware that hostip.info can be "way off".  For example if one's ISP is based in say Missouri but effectively located in Maryland, the location given may be "St Louis, MO" rather than Baltimore MD...

Answer (score 0):

http://tuq.in/tools/geo

is a free geolocation service also it is way awsome in quality