# Get zip code based on IP Address with Python

Tags: python, django, geolocation

Is it possible to find the zip code based on a users IP address using python / django (not geodjango)?  I assume I would have to use a web service, but I would really like to just be able to query a database if possible.

I am using geopy right now, so it would be cool if I could integrate that somehow.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1828334/free-web-service-to-determine-ip-address-zip-code

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can't collect a real zip code from an IP address as these are assigned by ISP's when you route threw their connection.

Comment: Of course you cant collect the real address of the user, but there are many services which help you approximate a user's address via their request IP address.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.ip2location.com/python.aspx

```
import IP2Location;

IP2LocObj = IP2Location.IP2Location();
IP2LocObj.open("data/IP-COUNTRY-SAMPLE.BIN");
rec = IP2LocObj.get_all("19.5.10.1");

print rec.zipcode
```

I don't have any experience with this package but it looks like it will do what you want.

EDIT: Actually it looks like this is just searching through a data file that they sell -- so probably not that useful if you are looking for something free.