# How can I get the Latitude and Longitude of a ZIP Code?

Tags: php

I need some help to get the Latitude and Longitude dynamically of a ZIP Code entered by the user. so that i can work to show the shop address on those area of zip code.

Comment: and then there was a duplicate question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1828334/free-web-service-to-determine-ip-address-zip-code

Comment: Okay, I cannot un-vote-up a comment, but @Gaurav is wrong, that is the _opposite_ of this question. However, they are closely related. Also, @Ibu is also wrong, that is asking to get the Zip Code from an IP Address.

Comment: and @sholsinger : I apologies for my mistake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google is running some kind of geocoding, you should check it out, it might help you
http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/

Answer (score 3):

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/

There is some requirements for that like you have to register your google account for that but it's very easy and you have to pass some parameter which is describe at there.

You can make using JSON or XML as per your requirements.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't specified what country you're looking to do this for but you can use the GeoNames API for [`postalCodeSearch`](http://www.geonames.org/export/web-services.html#postalCodeSearch).

For example (XML and JSON responses respectively)

```
http://api.geonames.org/postalCodeSearch?postalcode=90210&username=demo
http://api.geonames.org/postalCodeSearchJSON?postalcode=90210&username=demo
```

Comment: I need it for US .. First I will have to search CA and then outside?

Comment: YES! You are awesome. Thanks for sharing that resource. I've tried out a bunch of queries and this looks to be pretty awesome. Creative Commons Attribution License isn't too bad either.

Comment: @logudotcom It does US just fine. Canada is limited to the FSA only (First three characters) eg: http://api.geonames.org/postalCodeSearchJSON?postalcode=K1P&username=demo

Answer (score 2):

Going a little more in depth, you can get a JSON encoded object from google from the following url:

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=ZIPCODE&sensor=false

just replace the ZIPCODE with the zipcode that you would like and it should return to you a json object with the latitude and longitude coordinates.

Comment: Note that Google restricts the number of times you can do this per day and per arbitrary time limit to reduce "repurposing" of the API. (per the [documentation](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/#Limits))