# Location Longitude and Latitude

Tags: php, google-maps, maps

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I get the Latitude and Longitude of a ZIP Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5959305/how-can-i-get-the-latitude-and-longitude-of-a-zip-code)

Lets say I have a PHP field which asks for a city or a zip code. When user enters a city or a zip code, is it possible to get the longitude and latitude of given city/zip code?

Comment: yes it is. see posts on right

Comment: [http://gmaps-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/geocoder/singlegeocode.html](http://gmaps-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/geocoder/singlegeocode.html)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, read the Google map api. It is explained there + examples http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial.html

Answer (score 0):

According to this blogpost it is:
http://www.talkincode.com/find-longitude-and-latitude-of-postcode-or-zipcode-using-google-maps-and-php-442.html